# ANDROID - While loop inside Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops, while-loop

I create a thread to process some queue data. Inside the thread there is a unlimited while loop. when loop is working, the interface always freezing.

Im confused about this, I've created the thread, but why it still freezing ??

```
Thread queue = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
        while(true) {
          ...
        }
    }
  }); 
  queue.start;
```

Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: What do you need the while loop for? I suppose you try to do something in background? Then maybe check on AsyncTask

Comment: @Felix .. what you do in While loop is important.. hope its not creating objects...

Comment: yes youre right. I was use the asynctask, but its came up with same problem. I need the unlimited loop to watch when a variable changed.

Comment: post what you do in while loop... i mean code inside it...

Comment: @sandy no, im not creating objects. I was trying to monitor a variable to download some data from the internet. just like this 

inside the while loop : 
  if (address != null) {
     result = result + downloaddata(address);
  }

Comment: @FelixAnggaErlandhita - don't do that.  Get/Ask/Force whatever changes the variable to signal that it has changed, eg. Wait/Notify.

Comment: @MartinJames Can you give me some examples how wait/notify works ? seems to be useful :)

Comment: @FelixAnggaErlandhita - there are gazillions of examples on the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not just your interface slowing down, in fact your phone will be too because you are consuming (unnecessarily wasting) all the processing powers in a while loop. For better approach, use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and/or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or at least use `Thread.sleep` inside while-loop in your thread.

Comment: Oh, I think when I use a new thread, will not slowing down the interface ?

Comment: yes, it does create a new thread, but that thread also occupies the processor fully. Try putting **Thread.sleep(1000);** inside while-loop and you'll see the difference

Comment: Oh ok, thanks to you @Waqas. I'll try it. 
Im sorry, but my reputation isnt enough to vote up your solution :(